# Extract and store UTM parameters for SPA through GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager, backtracking, utm

I'm managing a single page app for on of my clients who is generating motor insurance quotes for users. we need to track our marketing campaigns efficiency by extracting the utm parameters from the url and store it so at the end we can know the source of each lead from the back end.

the only issue I face here is that, users for examples land on " [www.test.com/motor](http://www.test.com/motor) " which is a normal landing page but once the users clicks on Get a quote it takes him to " quote.test.com "

is there a step by step guide for me to be able to transfer the stored utm parameters to the next page and all pages in the journey ?

appreciate your help guys.

I expect to see on my sql database the source for each lead so I'll have a deeper look into my marketing efficiency.

Comment: Make an html tag that stores utm-parameters in cookies when they are set? That's just one step, but should constitute as a step by step guide. You should really show your attempts so that we could see what you're missing. Your question is way too open.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you tranfer to GA4 that can easily take care of cross-domain tracking. After the setup, GA4 should then natively inherit UTM from the second-level domain pageview and keep the session together even on quote.test.com

Your suggested approach would create a new session instance that would create duplicated sessions (1 for [www.test.com/motor](http://www.test.com/motor) and 1 for quote.test.com). I do not recommend this way. If you decide to go this path anyway, BNazaruk's answer is the way to go.